# turn table data source from html to a javascript object whilst maintaining the flex-wrap:wrap style

Tags: javascript, object, flexbox

I am having difficulty implementing flex-wrap:wrap on tables constructed from javascript objects. I can do it easily without javascript but that is anything but efficient. Can you helpme?
Below is the code sample of the desired output.

```css
        .table{
            /*max-width: 350px;*/
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Flexbox template for tables</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="table">
    <table class="#">
        <thead><tr class="#"><th>emotion</th><th>description</th><th>description</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr><td>happy</td><td>happy is a postive feeling</td><td>2</td></tr>
         <tr><td>sad</td><td>sad is a negative feeling</td><td>-3</td></tr>
         <tr><td>sleepy</td><td>sleepy is when one lacks sleep</td><td>-0.5</td></tr>
         <tr><td>eager</td><td>eager is where one can not wait to do or experience something.</td><td>3</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="#">
        <thead><tr class="#"><th>emotion</th><th>description</th><th>description</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr><td>happier</td><td>a stronger feeling than happy</td><td>2</td></tr>
         <tr><td>very sad</td><td>a stronger feeling than sad</td><td>-3</td></tr>
         <tr><td>knackered</td><td>a stronger feeling than sleepy</td><td>-0.5</td></tr>
         <tr><td>excited</td><td>a stronger feeling than eager</td><td>3</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    <table class="#">
        <thead><tr class="#"><th>emotion</th><th>description</th><th>description</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr><td>extatic</td><td>The strongest version of happy</td><td>2</td></tr>
         <tr><td>distraught</td><td>The strongest version of sad</td><td>-3</td></tr>
         <tr><td>fatigued</td><td>The strongest version of sleepy</td><td>-0.5</td></tr>
         <tr><td>very excited</td><td>The strongest version of excited</td><td>3</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    <table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue is that I lose the flex-wrap:wrap style on these tables when I try to build these tables using javascript. Can anyone help me fix this?

```
    let tbody = '<tbody>';
    // const objectTitles = { menuItem, description, value } of Object.values(feelings);
    for (const { menuItem, description, value } of Object.values(feelings)) {
        tbody += '<tr>';
        tbody += `<td class="menuItem">${menuItem}</td>`;
        tbody += `<div class="hide description">${description}</div>`;
        tbody += `<td>${value}</td>`;
        tbody += '</tr>';
    }
    for (const { menuItem, description, value } of Object.values(feelings2)) {
        tbody += '<tr>';
        tbody += `<td class="menuItem">${menuItem}</td>`;
        tbody += `<div class="hide description">${description}</div>`;
        tbody += `<td>${value}</td>`;
        tbody += '</tr>';
    }
  tbody += '</tbody>';
```

Comment: It works, the tables are side by side and the third one is under the first two because there's no more room left.

Comment: it works because that is when it is done using HTML. 
It does NOT work when I try to source data from an object or array with javascript. The issue is that both tables end up combined which makes it impossible to split into 2 different containers to enact flex-wrap:wrap

Comment: How exactly are you targeting tbody? There's 3 of them on the whole page.

Comment: Through the '.table' class.  I wrapped all three tables in a div element  with a '.table' class. 
When I try to do the same thing when sourcing tables from the object like the following, it does not work
        const feelings = [
                {
            menuItem: happy[0],
            description:  happy[1],
            value: 5
        },
        {
            menuItem: excited[0],
            description:  excited[1],
            value: 6
        }
]:

Comment: Your code does not reflect how and where it is applied. By your last comment and reviewing the code in rhe question, it sounds like you are rendering 3 tbodies to a div?

Comment: So you are saying I should add div elements to the objects?
If so how would you recommend I do that?

Comment: Your JavaScript only shows `<tbody>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`, and `<div>` but there's no code as how it's implemented. For instance, how is it rendered? `.innerHTML`? `.insertAdjacentHTML()`? Where in the DOM do you render that `<tbody>`?

Comment: I have rethought  my approach and have tried to make things clearer in this new post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71808962/how-to-add-multiple-div-tags-to-a-javascript-object