# how to add multiple <div> tags to a javascript object

Tags: javascript, html, object, innerhtml

I have a couple of objects and when I add them to the innerHTML I wish to encompass each object with a 'div' element. So 'feelings' would be encompassed with a set of 'div' elements and 'feelings2' would be encompassed in it's own set of 'div' elements.
Can anyone help me?

This below is the HTML that is referenced in the javascript code

```
<div class="tables">
<table > 

    <tbody class="row" id="tableData"></tbody>
</table>
```

These 2 are the object sample.

```
        const feelings = [
            {
        menuItem: happy[0],
        description:  happy[1],
        value: 5
    },
    {
        menuItem: excited[0],
        description:  excited[1],
        value: 6
    },
    {
        menuItem: sad[0],
        description:  sad[1],
        value: 1
    },
    {
        menuItem: furious[0],
        description:  furious[1],
        value: 0
    }
    ];
    const feelings2 = [
            {
        menuItem: happier[0],
        description:  happier[1],
        value: 5
    },
    {
        menuItem: excited2[0],
        description:  excited2[1],
        value: 6
    },
    {
        menuItem: sadder[0],
        description:  sadder[1],
        value: 1
    },
    {
        menuItem: furious2[0],
        description:  furious2[1],
        value: 0
    }
    ];
```

This is the javascript that adds the objects data to the innerHTML

```
let tbody = '<tbody>';

function addToTableBody(feeling) {
  let returnVal = "";
  for (const {
      menuItem,
      description,
      value
    } of Object.values(feeling)) {
    returnVal += 
    `
      <tr class="rows">
        <td class="menuItem">${menuItem}</td>
        <div class="hide description">${description}</div>
        <td>${value}</td>
      </tr>
    `
  }
  return returnVal;
}


tbody += addToTableBody(feelings)
tbody += addToTableBody(feelings2);

tbody += '</tbody>';
document.getElementById('tableData').innerHTML = tbody;
```

Comment: Ok and with this your tables come out missing? `document.getElementById('tableData').innerHTML = tbody;` will destroy everything within `#tableData` and then render `tbody`. Also, if a `<tbody>` is within a `<tbody>` I'm pretty sure that's invalid HTML so whatever behavior you'd expect from a table and it's table elements may not be evident.

Comment: You probably want to overwite the empty `<tbody>` with new `<tbody>`? If so use `.outerHTML` instead of `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

The example below features a function that will accept a DOM Object and an Array of Objects and render a HTML table with the keys as `<th>` and all of the values in `<td>`. Each object of the array must have the same keys. Couldn't use `feelings` since none of those arrays are defined yet -- so I used an arbitrary array consisting of objects with identical keys.

***Details are commented in example below***

```js
/** 
 * Input data must be an array of objects. 
 * Each object must have the same set of keys,
 */
const data = [
  {
    User: 'adurrant0',
    Email: 'barchdeckne0@reference.com',
    IPv4: '87.225.51.29',
    Log: '1634952921000',
  },
  {
    User: 'schatelet1',
    Email: 'adiggell1@kickstarter.com',
    IPv4: '144.187.55.254',
    Log: '1588558039000',
  },
  {
    User: 'ccocci2',
    Email: 'rmanger2@berkeley.edu',
    IPv4: '146.114.241.130',
    Log: '1626340081000',
  },
  {
    User: 'amulvin3',
    Email: 'rswaffield3@163.com',
    IPv4: '135.6.104.158',
    Log: '1641816474000',
  },
  {
    User: 'mthorley4',
    Email: 'czanolli4@a8.net',
    IPv4: '77.196.2.132',
    Log: '1639022902000',
  },
  {
    User: 'aluciano5',
    Email: 'hturfin5@squidoo.com',
    IPv4: '95.92.150.36',
    Log: '1627573711000',
  },
  {
    User: 'wallan6',
    Email: 'mseegar6@bloomberg.com',
    IPv4: '116.74.157.114',
    Log: '1636129472000',
  },
  {
    User: 'temloch7',
    Email: 'abilton7@smh.com.au',
    IPv4: '97.215.247.56',
    Log: '1641316862000',
  },
  {
    User: 'nspuner8',
    Email: 'pladd8@wordpress.com',
    IPv4: '231.37.19.22',
    Log: '1618192850000',
  },
  {
    User: 'xgwillim9',
    Email: 'rcisson9@moonfruit.com',
    IPv4: '100.150.5.236',
    Log: '1600825215000',
  }
];
// Reference the static element to add the table to
const main = document.querySelector('main');

// Pass in the DOM Object (node) and Object Array (objArray)
const genTable = (node, objArray) => {
  // htmlString to render
  const base = `<table><tbody></tbody></table>`;
  // Render htmlString to node
  node.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', base);
  // Reference the table
  const table = document.querySelector('table');
  // Reference the tBody
  const tB = table.tBodies[0];

  // Get an array of keys from the first object of array
  const headers = Object.keys(objArray[0]);
  // Create and add a thead
  const tH = table.createTHead();
  // Add a tr to thead
  const hRow = tH.insertRow();
  // For each key add a th with the key as it's content
  headers.forEach((hdr) => (hRow.insertCell().outerHTML = `<th>${hdr}</th>`));
  // For each object of array...
  objArray.forEach((obj) => {
    // Add a tr to tbody...
    let row = tB.insertRow();
    // Get an array of current objects values
    let rowData = Object.values(obj);
    // Add a td for each value
    rowData.forEach((data) => (row.insertCell().textContent = data));
  });
};

genTable(main, data);
```

```html
<main></main>
```